# How to set transition style programmatically and connect to storyboard UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

When I do the following I am unable to see any changes to the transition style that I set. I have tried changing it in code and also by setting the value directly on the storyboard view controller.

```
let vc =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditorViewController") as! EditorViewController
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .partialCurl
self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

However when I do the following the transition style works but I have no storyboard view associated with the view controller and errors are thrown.

```
let vc =  EditorViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .partialCurl
self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

Comment: Just a quick question but are you using a `UINavigationController` for the view controller that is showing the `EditorViewController`?

Comment: No not using a UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you are using `show()` and not `present()`.

I tried to replicate your scenario and it works with the show function when there is not a `UINavigationController`. I'm guessing that the `UINavigationController` takes over on how the transition happens. When I tried to do it though, both scenarios did not have the desired animation and full screen effect. If i did not have a `UINavigationController` then both scenarios were working. So I'm not too sure on what the error is, but I think you should use the `present()` function instead.

Comment: Hi, I don't have a UINavigationController and I have also tried with present as well. Still no luck and I am wondering if it is something else that is affecting it.

Comment: @ORStudios I would imagine it is, when I was trying it I made a new project with two nearly empty view controllers. Do you maybe have a segue already connected from the Storyboard that is being called?

Comment: No, I did try a segue but then removed it. I will see if I can find anything else that might be causing it. Thanks for the help though